# int**= int*[] Is this true for arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new at C++. Just got started with it. The problem I am having is again and again saying cannot convert `int**` to `int*`.

I know that in the compiler the arrays are interpreted the same as pointers, so is it true that if I am to write `a[]` then it'll be interpreted as `a*`
and if I write `a[]` where `a` is of the datatype `int*`, then it'll be interpreted as `int**`?

Comment: what is the problem with your first paragraph? Isn't it logical that a pointer to an integer, is something different than a pointer to a pointer to an integer?

Comment: `int**` is a pointer type to pointer to `int` while `int*[]` is an `int` pointer array type of unknown bounds.

Comment: Arrays are *not* the same as pointers.  However, under most circumstances, when the name of an array variable appears in an expression, it is converted to a pointer to the first element.  This is a subtle but important distinction.

Comment: No, arrays are not pointers. An array is a contiguous section of memory; a pointer is an address.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I am having is again and again saying cannot convert `int**`
>   to `int*`.

Which is a problem that can be reduced to the fact that a dereferenced `int**` (an `int*`) is not a dereferenced `int*` (an `int`).

**Pointers and `int`s can be quite different**, depending on your compiler and your machine. They don't even need to have the same size.

Just how is this is a "problem", exactly?

> I know that in the compiler the arrays are interpreted the same as pointers,

That's a *very* simplifying statement. An array can be interpreted as a **pointer to its first element**. A common case where this happens is when people try to pass arrays by value to a function, which the language does not allow.

The following functions are indeed identical:

```
void f(int a[])
{
    int first_element = a[0];
    int first_element_too = *a;
}

void f(int* a) // identical
{
    int first_element = a[0];
    int first_element_too = *a;
}
```

(Your linker will even complain about a redefinition if you try this.)

> so is it true that if I am to write `a[]` then it'll be interpreted as `a*`

I think you mean if you write `int a[]` then it's as if you wrote `int* a`?

Under certain circumstances.

> and if I write `a[]` where `a` is of the datatype `int*`,

That's impossible. If you write `a[]`, then it's part of a declaration, so `a` is not of type `int*` but of an array type.

I think what you really mean is an array of `int*` elements, i.e. an `int* a[]`.

> then it'll be interpreted as `int**`?

Under certain circumstances. Again, a typical case would be the attempt to pass the array by value:

```
void f(int* a[])
{
    int* first_element = a[0];
    int* first_element_too = *a;
}

void f(int** a) // identical
{
    int* first_element = a[0];
    int* first_element_too = *a;
}
```

Note how these two functions do *not* attempt to convert an `int**` to an `int*`. The `int*` is the **first element**.

---

By the way, while it certainly cannot hurt to study these low-level basics of C++, you should use `std::array` and `std::vector` in real code.

Answer (score 0):

Array is a contiguous memory of bytes.
Pointer is a few bytes which holds a memory address of other variable.

Array != Pointer.

although they are not the same , they share some link :

- the name of the array turns into a pointer to the first element

so this applies:

```
int arr[3];
arr == &arr[0]; //true
```

- when array is sent as function argument , it *decays* into pointer, so the signature

`void f (int arr[4])`

is the same as

`void f(int* arr)`

- Pointers are used to catch dynamically-allocated arrays:

`int* arr = new int[4];`

so array *can* be expressed as pointer when one of the conditions above applies.